# mysql: change datetime format when select * from table

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I need to query and fetch a row in a table and change the default datetime format `2015-09-15 00:00:00` to simply `Sep 02 2015`. Any idea how to achieve this?

I tried

```
SELECT 
    * 
from tablename 
where id=0; 

SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%b %d %Y') 
FROM tablename.
```

It returns two tables.

Comment: Select only the fields you need, formatted appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
select sub.comments_id, sub.comment, date_format(sub.date, '%b %d %Y'), sub.views 
from (select comments_id, comment, date, views from tablename where id=0) as sub;
```

The power of MySQL is in sub selection, take advantage of it.

Comment: thanks. the thing is I need to select all column from that row. the code you kindly helped can only select the date column of the row.

Comment: Oh ok, to do this I would need to know the fields in the table 'tablename'.

If you rather not tell me then solving this is easy. The subselect is only taking date from tablename, instead select all fields. Now that you have all the fields from the subselect, select all the fields from the subselect (not repeating date).

Comment: comments_id, comment,date,views

Comment: Ok so that should work but try and understand what is going on and not just copy paste even though I made it very easy to do so :).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query:

```
select date_format(str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'), '%b %d %Y') from tablename;
```

`str_to_date` converts string representation to `date` and `date_format` gets you the required formatted string.